# British 1990s/2000s crime novel featuring twin gangsters

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to recall a British crime thriller I read in the late 1990s/early 2000s. It was set in the 1960s and featured twin gangsters very obviously based on the real-life Kray twins, with some of the events based on ones experienced by the Krays. The storyline concerned their downfall due to the machinations of a rival gangster. I seem to recall that it was a paperback original.

EDIT: I remember that the twins had a corrupt policeman as an ally, who killed himself when everything started going wrong.

Comment: I thought this might be *Twins* (1977) by Bari Wood and Jack Geasland, but (a) it's American and (2) it's the wrong twins

Comment: Could the twins have been named "the Ryan twins"?